# Python Pandas: regroup data horizontally for every fifteen-minutes-range

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am very new to Python for data analysis and my task is to re-organize an auto-generated csv-file, in which four companies are monitored in their energy-consume (in megawatt) for the whole month of July 2022.
The energy-consume is reported for the companies every 15 minutes from July 1 (00:15) until July 31 (23:45). This is how the original dataframe looks like:

| Index | Date | Quarter | Company | Mw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company A | 0 |
| 2 | 01.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company B | 0 |
| 3 | 01.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company C | 10 |
| 4 | 01.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company D | 15 |
| 1 | 01.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company A | 0 |
| 2 | 01.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company B | 0 |
| 3 | 01.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company C | 1 |
| 4 | 01.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company D | 150 |
| 1 | 01.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company A | -130 |
| 2 | 01.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company B | 120 |
| 3 | 01.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company C | 110 |
| 4 | 01.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company D | 0 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |
| 1 | 02.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company A | 0 |
| 2 | 02.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company B | 0 |
| 3 | 02.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company C | 160 |
| 4 | 02.07.2022 | 00:15 | Company D | 180 |
| 1 | 02.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company A | 10 |
| 2 | 02.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company B | 0 |
| 3 | 02.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company C | -145 |
| 4 | 02.07.2022 | 00:30 | Company D | 150 |
| 1 | 02.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company A | -180 |
| 2 | 02.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company B | 115 |
| 3 | 02.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company C | 145 |
| 4 | 02.07.2022 | 00:45 | Company D | 0 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |

This is how the new data frame should look like. All the megawatt-values should be reported horizontally for every fifteen-minutes-range until the end of July grouped by Date and Company:

| Date | Company | 00:00-00:15 | 00:15-00:30 | 00:30-00:45 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 | Company A | 0 | 0 | -130 |  |
| 01.07.2022 | Company B | 0 | 0 | 120 |  |
| 01.07.2022 | Company C | 10 | 1 | 110 |  |
| 01.07.2022 | Company D | 15 | 150 | 0 |  |
|  | … |  |  |  |  |
| 02.07.2022 | Company A | 0 | 10 | -180 |  |
| 02.07.2022 | Company B | 0 | 0 | 115 |  |
| 02.07.2022 | Company C | 160 | -145 | 145 |  |
| 02.07.2022 | Company D | 180 | 150 | 0 |  |
|  | … |  |  |  |  |

Since I have never programmed with Python before, I am very confused on how would be the best way to reach this task. I am not asking you to give me the whole solution, just a hint on which would be the best methods from Pandas (stack/unstack, pivot). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you would use the `groupby` method.

Answer (score 0):

I applied a pivot_table to the dataframe, where the indices are 'Company', 'Date', values 'Mw'. Columns are created from 'Quarter' rows. In the received data, indexes are reset using reset_index().
The data looks like this:

```
Quarter        Date    Company  00:15  00:30  00:45
0        01.07.2022  Company A      0      0   -130
1        01.07.2022  Company B      0      0    120
2        01.07.2022  Company C     10      1    110
3        01.07.2022  Company D     15    150      0
4        02.07.2022  Company A      0     10   -180
5        02.07.2022  Company B      0      0    115
6        02.07.2022  Company C    160   -145    145
7        02.07.2022  Company D    180    150      0
```

To order them as in your example sort_values(by='Date') is used.
Delete the index name:

```
df1.rename_axis(None, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Indexes are set from 0 to n.

Next, in the list generator, the names of the required columns are created and they are renamed.
All together:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', header=0)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'Company'], columns='Quarter', values='Mw')

df1 = df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='Date')
df1.rename_axis(None, axis=1, inplace=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(np.arange(0, len(df1)))

hist = len(df1.columns)
arr = ['00:00' + '-' + str(df1.columns[2])]
[arr.append(df1.columns[i - 1] + '-' + df1.columns[i]) for i in range(3, hist)]
df1.columns.values[2:] = arr#Renaming columns
print(df1)
```

Output

```
         Date    Company  00:00-00:15  00:15-00:30  00:30-00:45
0  01.07.2022  Company A            0            0         -130
1  01.07.2022  Company B            0            0          120
2  01.07.2022  Company C           10            1          110
3  01.07.2022  Company D           15          150            0
4  02.07.2022  Company A            0           10         -180
5  02.07.2022  Company B            0            0          115
6  02.07.2022  Company C          160         -145          145
7  02.07.2022  Company D          180          150            0
```